# How to register event in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagrid

I am trying to make grid clickable in `ASP.net` ... Everything is fine when I set `EnableEventValidation="false"` but when I make it "`true`" I got this exception.

> Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security
>   purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
>   events originate from the server control that originally rendered
>   them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.

I try this code to register event in Render method but still happening samething.

```
foreach (GridViewRow gr in grid_Products.Rows)
    {
        if (gr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < gr.Cells.Count; columnIndex++)
            {
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(gr.UniqueID , columnIndex.ToString());//+ "$ct100"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting the binding code in

```
if(!IsPostback)

{    

//bind gridview

}
```